# Where do you recommend I learn about forms and do I need to?

Tags: php, html, forms

I understand most HTML now and I was thinking of moving on to php. My issue is that I never learned about forms because it was never necessary when no dynamic website was involved. It appears to me that to get php to interact with HTML properly that forms are required. Are forms an essential part of php? Where is it recommended that I learn about them?

Comment: I'd say any decent tutorial or book you will want to read to learn about PHP will also contain the necessary basics about HTML forms. Yes, if you want your users to input any text, forms are necessary. Just pick any good PHP book (search, there are already many questions about this).

Comment: @AgentConundrum: The very first example on that w3schools page you linked to has invalid HTML. Please don't refer newbies to that site, it's full of errors. In fact, all those examples of form markup are awful. They even go so far as to *sell* bogus "certification" to the unaware, yet they are an authority on absolutely nothing.

Comment: W3 schools should be avoided at all costs. It is in no way associated with the W3C and they have been trying to distance themselves from W3 schools for a long time.

Comment: I only recently found out that W3 Schools wasn't associated with W3C. Which really shocked me as I was considering a certification. After seeing other peoples comments on the subject, it doesn't seem like such a good idea.

Comment: @Sam152 Fair enough. I've deleted the comment. I did hesitate before linking there, since I'm not a particular fan of the site either. I guess since I'm guilty of using it as a reference on occasion, since I can spot the mistakes easy enough that I can use it as a quick reminder for some things, I didn't think it through from the perspective of a beginner. Sorry.

Comment: Of course you may have heard of http://w3fools.com/, but even that site doesn't fully cover how awful w3schools truly are. However,  there are some great links to tutorials at the bottom of the page, have a look :)

Comment: That's what's great about a site like this though. We can all share our opinions on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, forms are an often-used method of getting information from the end user into the script.  [HTML Dog](http://htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/forms/) has a good overview of them (and FYI, I find HTML Dog to be a good resource for HTML stuff in general).

Comment: Thanks. All of the HTML Dog tutorials look great.

Comment: I approve of this message :) HTML Dog is a very good site.

Comment: I tried a few minutes ago but it told me I had to wait :). I can now. Thanks.

Comment: FYI I'd give you rep, but I don't have enough myself yet. :(

Answer (score 2):

Forms are essential to your PHP and HTML development. With any dynamic content, taking user input from a form is going to be one of the most useful items in your toolkit. The basic concept are quite easy to understand to someone who already knows HTML. The [tizag tutorials aren't bad](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php), and they are pretty up to date.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I'll have a read through the Tizag tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Forms are very important when integrating the two languages(php and html).  Forms are used to take user input; for example, a username/password field would be a form.  The username and password are passed from html to php using either of two methods, post or get.  You can learn more about these by doing a few google searches.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Judging by the other people comments, I won't be using W3schools again. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Have you looked at W3fools? They display a lot of the errors W3Schools made and are making.

Comment: Wesley, was the -1 really necessary?  I mean, i was just giving my personal thoughts on the subject... I've used w3schools before and i haven't seen any problems myself, my projects have worked perfectly.  I don't see why my answer should be so despised.

Comment: @Corecase: If you edit your post I can remove the downvote, but as long as you link to w3schools as a reference it will remain. The idea of the site is to promote good answers, so although it was not *necessary*, it was indeed appropriate, and not personal in any way. I'm not kidding though, that site is a scourge to the web and causes more harm than good, the problem is that they have a stranglehold on the search engine traffic. Here is another fairly good ref site: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html, and http://htmldog.com/ is also very good.

Comment: Honestly, i didn't know that it was such a bad site, thanks for letting me know.  I removed the link from my answer.

Comment: Happy to oblige, sorry to come off strong but I have strong feelings about it, and as you can see so do many others. Read the links at the bottom of http://w3fools.com/ for more info on how to get good, accurate search results and reference. Simply blocking them from your search results opens up a world of good reference sites.

Comment: I understand and i didn't take it personally. :)  Thanks for the link.